# i can't install sharepoint server 2013 in my computer

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I want to take the Sharepoint 2013 certification for developing applications (70-488,70-489)

so to learn sharepoint i want to try a demo

i can't install it in my computer (2GB RAM 32 bit ) .

my question is : their is a way to try an existing demo ? (in a cloud for exemple  )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With this specification, it is not possible to install SharePoint on it.
You can try:

- [Office 365 (SharePoint Online)](http://products.office.com/en-us/SharePoint/compare-sharepoint-plans)
- [90 day free trail of windows azure.](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0018p/)
- [check this](http://sharepointballet.com/2013/06/12/10-ways-to-get-sharepoint-2013-demo-environment/)